# Replacing NA in column with values in adjacent column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

I have a dataframe as such:

```
  A       B        C       D       E       F        G        H
  a     LOW      1.5     0.2      NA    1000     2000       NA
  b     LOW      2.9     0.4    HIGH    6000     1000       NA
  c     LOW        1     1.3     LOW     400     1111      LOW 
  d     LOW        2      10     LOW    1000      400     HIGH
```

How do I do a conditional statement to replace the `NA` values.

For column E, I want to take the difference of column C and column D, and if it is less than 0, display "small decrease", if it is above 0, then display "small increase".

And then for for column H, do the same thing except using the difference of column F and column G. Display "small decrease" if below 0, and "small increase" if above 0.

Final output should look like this:

```
  A       B        C       D                 E       F        G                    H
  a     LOW      1.5     0.2    Small Increase    1000     2000       Small Decrease
  b     LOW      2.9     0.4              HIGH    6000     1000       Small Increase
  c     LOW        1     1.3               LOW     400     1111                  LOW 
  d     LOW        2      10               LOW    1000      400                 HIGH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perform similar steps for other column too!

```
df$E <- ifelse(is.na(df$E), ifelse(df$C-df$D <0,"small decrease","small increase"), df$E)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `set` from `data.table` which would be very efficient as it assigns value in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)#converts 'data.frame' to 'data.table'
#loop through the index of the concerned columns
for(j in c(5L, 8L)) {
  #get the row index of NA for each column
  i1 <- which(is.na(df1[[j]])) 
  #get the value to be replaced based on the difference
  val <- c("Small Increase", "Small Decrease")[((df1[[j-2]][i1] - df1[[j-1]][i1]) < 0) + 1]
  #set the NA elements to the above val
  set(df1, i = i1, j = j, value = val)
 }

df1
#   A   B   C    D              E    F    G              H
#1: a LOW 1.5  0.2 Small Increase 1000 2000 Small Decrease
#2: b LOW 2.9  0.4           HIGH 6000 1000 Small Increase
#3: c LOW 1.0  1.3            LOW  400 1111            LOW
#4: d LOW 2.0 10.0            LOW 1000  400           HIGH
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), B = c("LOW", "LOW", 
"LOW", "LOW"), C = c(1.5, 2.9, 1, 2), D = c(0.2, 0.4, 1.3, 10
), E = c(NA, "HIGH", "LOW", "LOW"), F = c(1000L, 6000L, 400L, 
1000L), G = c(2000L, 1000L, 1111L, 400L), H = c(NA, NA, "LOW", 
"HIGH")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```